# difference in id() between list and string type in python

Tags: python

Just for my curiosity, I was trying two different tests

```
a='apple'
b='apple'
```

Here id(a) and id(b) returned same.

But If i assign

```
 a=[1,2,3]
 b=[1,2,3]
```

id() returns different value for both.

Why id() is returning different value for list/dict while its returning same for a string type [ for same data content]?

Comment: For immutable types such as strings, it *doesn't make any difference* if two equal objects happen to share the same address, and some memory can be saved if this does happen.  For mutable objects such as lists, this can't be allowed to happen, as it would result in changes to one object unexpectedly showing up in the other object.

Comment: Thanks ! @jasonharper